# setting Room back to available

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have a problem with my booking system. in the table rooms i have a column named isAvailable with datatype bit. when the Registereduser books a room from gridview with selected index this column is set to 0 where. all that works fine but now i have to update the table when a staff user deletes a selected booking. my idea is saving index of deleted row in array and compares index of table Rooms and table Bookings. if index is not found sets the isAvailable back to 1 thus making it available. is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new flag and set IsDeleted to true? That way having two flags you can see if the Room was deleted when Available or Deleted when Unavailable and give you more auditing data over your staff.

Comment: i didnt quite understand this concept. the staff user will not delete a booking when the room is available. i have a table bookings which saves room id user id checkin date and checkout date. i need to set the room to available when the booking of that room is deleted. sry if i didnt explain myself very good

Comment: @Karol - ah okay.  Do you need the code to do it or just wondering if this is the best approach?  Your approach seems fine, if you need the code I could help you write the trigger/statement

Comment: i need the code if possible and thank you very much for you help

Comment: Can i ask you and other question unrelated to the previous one